# how to mock.SingleOrDefault() with Moq and C#

Tags: c#, moq

I've seen a few questions like this floating around but I'm looking for a good explination of how to get around this.    I understand that Moq can't mock the extension call, but I'm just looking for a really good example.   In the current code I there is a call like

```
var thing = listOfthings.myList.SingleOrDefault(lt => lt.Name== "NameToFind");
```

I've tried

```
MockedlistOfThings.Setup(x => x.myList.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Name == "NameToFind")).Returns(fakeObject);
```

Just looking for a good work around. thanks.

To further elaborate on how this situation came up, we are currently running a translation engine against large sets of data, that has to be run line by line.  This translation engine passes in an Interface called IListOfthings.   listOfthings is actually holding reference data in a dictionary that is preloaded in another call higher up in the program.    I have created a "fakeObject" <- dictionary that holds my fake data that the method can use. I have Mocked the IlistOfthings which is passed in to the calling method. but I don't see how to fake the SingleOrDefault call. 
Simplifed method below.

```
Public class ClassIMTesting 
{

public void Translate(myObject obj, IlistOfThings listOfthings){

    var thing = listOfthings.MyList.SingleOrDefault(lt => lt.Name== "NameToFind");
//Other logic here ..... 
    }
}



public class Thing()
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary MyDict { get; set; }
}


[TestFixture()]
public class MyCodeTest
{

     MyObject myObj;
     Mock<IListOfthings> listOfThings;
     Thing thing;



    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {

        myObj = new MyObject();


        _thing = new thing();
        _thing.Name = "MyName";

        var myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        myDict.Add("70,~", "");
        myDict.Add("70,145", "expectedResult");
        myDict.Add("911,", "expectedResult");

        thing.MyDict = myDict;


        listOfThings = new Mock<IListOfthings>();

        listOfThings.Setup(x => x.MyList.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Name == "MyName")).Returns(thing);

    }





    [TestCase("70", "~", "70070")]
    [TestCase("70", "145", "expectedResult")]
    [TestCase("911", "", "expectedResult")]
    public void TranslateTest(string iTC, string ITCode, string expectedResult)
    {
        myObject.ITC = iTC;
        myObject.ITCode = iTCode;


        ClassIMTesting p = new ClassIMTesting();


        p.Translate(myObject, listofThings.Object);


        Assert.That(myObject.ITC3Code, Is.EqualTo(expectedResult));
    }
}

public interface IListOfThings
{
    List<Thing> MyList{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: mock the thing that builds `listOfthings`

Comment: You need to ask yourself why you're mocking up that extension call to begin with. I think you're probably shooting for coverage and you should be shooting for proper testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
public interface IListOfThings {
    List<Thing> MyList { get; set; }
}

public class Thing() {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary MyDict { get; set; }
}
```

In order to provide a mock to satisfy the following example

```
public class ClassImTesting  {

    public Thing Translate(IlistOfThings listOfthings){

        var thing = listOfthings.MyList.SingleOrDefault(lt => lt.Name== "NameToFind");

        return thing
    }
}
```

The mock just needs to return a collection that will allow the `SingleOrDefault` extension to behave as expected when invoked.

For example

```
//Arrrange
Mock<IListOfthings> listOfThings = new Mock<IListOfthings>();
var thing = new Thing {
    Name = "NameToFind",
    //...
};
List<Thing> list = new List<Thing>() { thing };

listOfThings.Setup(_ => _.MyList).Returns(list);

var subject = new ClassImTesting();

//Act
var actual = subject.Translate(listOfThings.Object);

//Assert
Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(thing));
```

By having the mock return an actual `List<Thing>`, when

```
var thing = listOfthings.MyList.SingleOrDefault(lt => lt.Name== "NameToFind");
```

is invoked, the `SingleOrDefault` extension acts on a list where I can behave as expected.